# Can you remove 2D landmarks from the map in HERE Android SDK?

Tags: android, here-api

My question is pretty simple, I want to remove all the landmarks except my endpoint marker from the map once I call `NavigationManager.navigate()` or `NavigationManager.simulate()` is that possible to do?
if it is then what do I need to use?

PS- I set `setLandmarksVisible()` to false but apparently it only hides 3d landmarks.

*by 2d landmarks I mean these
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the extruded buildings, you can configure this in SDK 3.x like this:

SDK for Android supports 3D representations of buildings and structures. This feature is called extruded buildings, and you can display them by using setExtrudedBuildingsVisible() method in com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map.
See: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.17/dev_guide/topics/map-extruded-buildings.html

If you mean 2D Carto POIs (as your image above), then you can disable this in SDK 3.x via Map.setCartoMarkersVisible e.g.:

```
 map.setCartoMarkersVisible(IconCategory.ALL, false);
```

See: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.17/api_reference_java/index.html?com%2Fhere%2Fandroid%2Fmpa%2Fmapping%2FMap.html

Comment: Hey, i did not mean extruded buildings just 2d landmarks. I attached a image to give you a clear idea. I'm on SDK 3.17

Comment: Ah, thanks for the image. Clarifies things. 
These types are called "Carto POI". 
I'll adapt my answer in a minute.